# angularjs tooltip: tooltip html template not updating

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tooltip

I was using [this angularjs tooltip library](https://github.com/720kb/angular-tooltips) to show tooltips.

Here's my **HTML:**

```
<span tooltips tooltip-title="Recommenders" tooltip-show-trigger="click" tooltip-view="/static/templates/tooltips/recommenders.html" tooltip-view-ctrl="FeedCtrl"></span>
```

Here's my **tooltip partial:**

```
<div ng-repeat="recommender in recommenders_list">
    {{recommender}}
</div>
```

The problem I am facing is that when I update the 'recommenders_list' array in my controller, the same is not reflected in the tooltip template.
How can I update my tooltip partial?

Comment: your main module has the dependency of the tooltip library? usually for something like that i create a new directive that return the template by url. this directive is inside on the same module of my controller

Comment: yes it has the dependancy. Can you please provide a plunker? That would really help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> mainFile

```
'use strict';

angular.module('yourAppName')
    .controller('ControllerName', ['$scope', function (scope) {

        // ...
        // here your list
        // ...
    }]);
```

> directiveFile

```
angular.module('yourAppName')
    .directive('directiveName', function() {
        return {
            templateUrl : 'url/of/your/template.html'
        };
    });
```

> htmlFile

```
<body ng-app="yourAppName">

    <div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="ControllerName">
        <div directive-name></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Angular file -->
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Angular mainFile -->
    <script src="url/of/your/mainFile.js"></script>

</body>
```

look at this example, is really basic but in this way i hope you can understand and find where could be your problem.

Comment: I don't see how this can be used as a tooltip? How will I adjust the tooltip's position?