# AngularJS tooltips/popovers with ng-repeated content

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tooltip

I am using Foundation 5 with AngularJS in my project. I have the following use case:

1. Click on a 'div' which is inside an ng-repeat.
2. Fetch a list specific to that div in response to the click.
3. Show that list in an ng-repeat in a tooltip/popover of that div(which was clicked).

**How do I go about generating that tooltip?**

I tried:

1. [this library](https://github.com/720kb/angular-tooltips) but I encountered some issues as mentioned in this [question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32842839/angularjs-tooltip-tooltip-html-template-not-updating?noredirect=1#comment53520604_32842839)
2. [angular-foundation](http://pineconellc.github.io/angular-foundation/), but the popovers here don't have a popover-template functionality(like in ui.bootstrap).

AND I don't want to use ui.bootstrap because I am using Foundation 5 (Its a bad idea, right?).

Comment: can you create demo using jsfiddle or plunkr

Comment: demo for what? I am asking for an approach, I don't have an approach right now.

Comment: use angular-foundation in it you can set html template

Comment: html template is fine, but in that template I need ng-repeated content which updates when the content is changed in the controller. I dont see any support for this in angular-foundation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cannot say what "approach" exactly you need, in your particular case (`fetch a list of something after something else has been clicked`) - but you can always generate the content of the tooltip on the fly :

```
<a href="#" class="has-tip" tooltip-html-unsafe="{{ buildToolTip() }}">TEST</a>
```

function :

```
$scope.buildToolTip = function() {
   var list = ''
   for (var i=0;i<3;i++) {
      list+='<li><em>element #'+i+'</em></li>';
   }
   return '<ul>'+list+'</ul>' 
}
```

now use the outcome of "*Fetch a list specific to that div in response to the clic*k" instead of the demonstration loop - you have the fetched list stored in a `$scope` variable somewhere anyway, I assume?

**http://plnkr.co/edit/3P9PSN2FsRyViCVlqReg?p=preview**